# Curl post request doesn't seem to work after adding HTTP forms

Tags: javascript, php, rest, api, curl

I am trying to add a port to my shadowsocks server using the restful api.

The JS code takes the user id of the site and turns it into curl code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addUser() {
// Get user id
var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
// Take user id text
var uid = div.textContent;
// Multiply by 1 to make sure JS thinks it's a number
var multiply = uid*1
// Generate password
var pass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999) + 10000000000 ;
// Generate port number
var port = 1024 + multiply; 
// Change format to fit cURL
var curl = '{"port": ' + port + ',"password":"' + pass + '"}';  
// Push to HTML
document.getElementById("curl").innerHTML = curl;
}
onload=addUser;
```

PHP code - When I just type the code JS script generated manually `{"port": 1025,"password":"26909395438"}` it works. Whenever I turn it into a form it stops working.

```
<?php
$curl = $_REQUEST['curl'];
$data = array('curl'=>$curl);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://[ip]:4001/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;     Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer     [token]";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' .
            curl_error($ch);
?>
```

and my HTML code that posts the php code.

```
<p id="code"></p>
<form action="/create-beta.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="curl" id="curl">
<br>
```

I am new to coding and I've been digging around the internet to put this together. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your form has no data in it. Just an (empty) hidden field. So if you are expecting there to be a port number and password from it then that won't work. You would have to add fields that can be filled in.

Comment: @dirk the hidden field gets filled by JavaScript code.